# How to get full location from Microsoft Graph CalendarView Delta API request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We found two different behaviours creating an event using Outlook Desktop and Outlook Web (OWA).

Consider create an event A with Outlook Desktop and event B with Outlook Web (OWA) with two "rooms" (location).

Result of event created with Outlook Desktop:

```
"locations": [
    {
      "displayName": "Room 1; Room 2",
      "locationType": "default",
      "uniqueId": "Room 1; Room 2",
      "uniqueIdType": "private"
    }
],
```

Result of event created with Outlook Web OWA:

```
"locations": [
    {
      "displayName": "Room 1",
      "locationType": "conferenceRoom",
      "uniqueId": "room1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
      "uniqueIdType": "directory",
      "locationUri": "room1@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
      "address": {
        "street": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "countryOrRegion": "",
        "postalCode": ""
      },
      "coordinates": {}
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Room 2",
      "locationUri": "room2@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
      "locationType": "conferenceRoom",
      "uniqueId": "room2@xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
      "uniqueIdType": "directory",
      "address": {
        "street": "",
        "city": "",
        "state": "",
        "countryOrRegion": "",
        "postalCode": ""
      },
      "coordinates": {}
    }
],
```

Why when the event is created with Outlook Desktop the "locations" field comes shorten? Is it a bug?

How to always get the full "locations" (like Outlook Web OWA result), no matter with what Outlook version?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/location?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource will on return populated properties. So if the application that created the [`Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/event?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) doesn't specify an `address`, `coordinates`, or `locationUri`, then the API won't return them.

Comment: I agree with you about "location" thanks. And about "locations" with "s" that usually comes with the properties of the location specified? Is there a way to set up the Outlook Desktop to always return the full location with this properties?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `locations` is just a collection of `location` resources. I can't speak to what Outlook for Windows/Mac does but the API has no control over how any given application. The API can only return the data it's been provided.

Comment: We don't know your networking, but we'd like to suggest you expose it as a "bug", because in our application we make use of this data to do some action. Considering two different behaviours, one with data and other without, we can't solve by our side to take the right action. Thank you so much!